# Регулярка после curl не пережевывает данные

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, парсер

Получаю с сервера через curl данные в utf.

Сервер любит укорачивать текст, просто перерубая строку побайтово, таким образом в тексте полно � в концах строки, после чего стоит троеточие

Если я через curl возьму этот текст и дам его регулярке, то регулярка откажется его обрабатывать

$return = str_replace("�","",$return); не убрало проблемные места

$return= mb_convert_encoding($return, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');  отчасти помогло, но теперь в тексте стало проскакивать conomicئnbsp;.. , что тоже регуляркой не пережевывается

Comment: для начала напишите код отправки/получения данных

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте через `preg_replace('/(�)/', '', $input_lines);` .
рабочий пример - https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/q2v

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: Мне кажется лучше всеё-таки работать с мультибайтовыми строками, а не исправлять последствия ошибки(вместо того чтобы её избежать).

Comment: Полностью согласен))